# How do I display fractions of a second in my time formatting function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, ruby-on-rails-5, duration

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a method that is supposed to help display a duraiton in milliseconds in a more readable format (hours:minutes:seconds) ...

```
  def time_formatted time_in_ms 
    regex = /^(0*:?)*0*/ 
    Time.at(time_in_ms/1000).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S").sub!(regex, '') 
  end
```

This works basically fine, but it doesn't work completely accurately when the time in milliseconds contains fractions of a second.  That is, if the time in milliseconds is

```
2486300
```

The above displays

```
41:26
```

but really it should display

```
41:26.3
```

How can I adjust my function so it will also display fractions of a second, assuming there are any?

Answer (score 2):

- For accuracy make sure you're returning a float (I've used `to_f` to do this).
- Append the argument to `strftime` with `".%1N"` for 1-digit milliseconds.

```
def time_formatted time_in_ms
  regex = /^(0*:?)*0*/ 
  Time.at(time_in_ms.to_f/1000).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%1N").sub!(regex, '') 
end

time_formatted 2486300
#=> "41:26.3"
```

For more information see [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) in the official Ruby documentation.

Comment: Thanks to a comment from this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23823) for a markdown issue.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust the above such that if there is no fraction of a second (i.e. ".0") that the ".0" won't get displayed?

Comment: @Dave that's a tricky one to be honest. The only think I can think of is appending the second line in your method with `.sub(/\.0\z/,'')`. But this seems pretty clumsy and inelegant.